# Devops CICD run ReactJS application while testing with jest + puppeteer

Tags: gitlab, puppeteer, gitlab-ci

**Scenario**

I'm working on getting my end-to-end tests to work in a GitLab pipeline. Currently all the tests run locally but I'm having an issue getting them to run using GitLab's continuous integration feature.

When running the tests locally puppeteer will use a headless version of chrome for end-to-end tests but the ReactJS' CRA server ***has*** to be running for this to work. To get the CRA server running locally I use `npm start` in one terminal and once it is fully running I can run `npm test` in a different terminal. During testing Puppeteer uses headless Chromium to run e2e tests on the site.

**The Issue**

`npm start` starts my CRA server but that process doesn't stop as I'm not sure how to stop it unless I manually quit it. This hangs docker and blocks me from ever starting my tests.

**Question**

How can I start my application with `npm start` and once it starts then run `npm run test:e2e` ? Ultimately I'd like to quit CRA once the tests are completed.

**Current Pipeline yml**

```
image: node:10.19.0
stages:
  - test
  - build
  - deploy

cache:
  # untracked: true
  key:
    files:
      - package-lock.json
  paths:
    - node_modules
#test_async:
#  script:
#    - npm install
#    - node ./specs/start.js ./specs/async.spec.js

before_script:
  - apt-get update && apt-get install -y lftp gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
  - if [ ! -d "node_modules" ]; then npm install; fi

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm start
    - npm run test:e2e

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm run build

# deploy-to-staging:
#   stage: deploy
#   script:
#     - lftp -e "open ftp.mediajackagency.com; user $MJA_FTP_USER $MJA_FTP_PASS; mirror --reverse --verbose build/ /var/www/domains/projects/my-project/build/; bye"
#   environment:
#     name: staging
#     url: http://dev.mediajackagency.com/projects/my-project/build
#   when: manual
#   only:
#     - dev
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to using a production build for testing by use of a local webserver. I leveraging the `[jest-puppeteer][1]` library which allows you to start a webserver with your tests.

**jest-puppeteer.config.js**

```
/**
 * find all flags at the following site @jkr
 * https://jestjs.io/docs/en/cli
 */

module.exports = {
    launch: {
        devtools: true, // allows for use of 'debugger;' in tests
        // executablePath: '/usr/bin/chromium-browser',
        headless: true,
        defaultViewport: {
            width: 1024,
            height: 768,
            //isMobile: true,
            //hasTouch: true,
        },
        ignoreDefaultArgs: ['--disable-extensions'],
        args: [
            '--enable-font-antialiasing',
            '--font-render-hinting=medium',
            '--disable-gpu',
            '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
            '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
            '--no-first-run',
            '--no-sandbox', // GOOD
            '--no-zygote',
            '--single-process', // GOOD

            "--renderer",
            "--no-service-autorun",
            "--no-experiments",
            "--no-default-browser-check",
            "--disable-extensions",
        ]
    },
    server: { // launches webserver just for tests @jkr
        // command: 'node server.js',
        command: 'npm run test:webserver'
        // port: 4444,
    },
    browser: 'chromium',
    browserContext: 'default'
};
```

**.gitlab-ci.yml**

```
image: node:10.19.0 # https://hub.docker.com/_/node/
# image: node:latest

cache:
  # untracked: true
  key: my-project-name
  # key: ${CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG} # per branch
  # key:
  #   files:
  #     - package-lock.json # only update cache when this file changes (not working) @jkr
  paths:
    - .npm/
    - node_modules
    - build

stages:
  - prepare # can install ci-deps here ? @jkr
  - test # uses test:build specifically @jkr
  - build
  - deploy

# before_install:

before_script:
  - npm ci --cache .npm --prefer-offline #
#   # - apt-get update && apt-get install -y lftp gconf-service libasound2 libatk1.0-0 libatk-bridge2.0-0 libc6 libcairo2 libcups2 libdbus-1-3 libexpat1 libfontconfig1 libgcc1 libgconf-2-4 libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 libglib2.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libnspr4 libpango-1.0-0 libpangocairo-1.0-0 libstdc++6 libx11-6 libx11-xcb1 libxcb1 libxcomposite1 libxcursor1 libxdamage1 libxext6 libxfixes3 libxi6 libxrandr2 libxrender1 libxss1 libxtst6 ca-certificates fonts-liberation libappindicator1 libnss3 lsb-release xdg-utils wget
#   - if [ ! -d "node_modules" ]; then set NODE_ENV=dev && npm install; fi # make sure dev dependencies are installed todo: 'if' needs to be verified working @jkr
#   # - npm install
#   # - if [ ! -d "build" ]; then npm run build; fi

prepare: # could this job be in a before_script for test ? @jkr
  stage: prepare
  script:
    - npm install
    - npm run build:test
  # cache:
  #   paths:
  #     - node_modules
  #   policy: push

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - npm run test:ci-deps
    - npm run test:e2e # runs puppeteer tests @jkr

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - npm run build
  # artifacts:
  #   paths:
  #     - build

deploy-ftp:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - lftp -e "open ftp.my.domain.com; user $MJA_FTP_USER $MJA_FTP_PASS; mirror --reverse --verbose build/ /var/www/domains/dev/projects/my-project/build/; bye"
  environment:
    name: staging
    url: http://my.domain.com/my-project/build
  when: manual
  only:
    - dev
```